# Messed up Exim queue - messages with header file but no data

Tags: linux, email, exim

My Exim mail queue was full of spam so I ran a custom grep command to search out spooled messages that contained the spam terms.  Problem is, I didn't know that Exim breaks messages up into multiple files (one for header information, one for data, etc.) so my grep command deleted the data files while leaving the header files.

Does anyone know of a way I can easily find and delete messages in the queue that have a header file but no data file?  Or another way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find them:

```
exipick '$message_body_missing'
```

Find and delete them:

```
exipick -i '$message_body_missing' | xargs exim -Mrm
```

Comment: Thanks, I've read exipick works well for this but it's not installed on my CentOS/cPanel server and I can't find a good tutorial on installing it.  Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Rather amusingly, I can.  Get a copy of it from jetmore.org/john/code/exipick, make it executable, and change the $spool variable to point to your local site's spool (find your local spool with `exim -bP | grep spool_directory`).

Comment: Haha, what are the odds?  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For lack of exipick,

```
cd /var/spool/exim/input
find -name "*-H" -exec sh -c 'H={}; if [ ! -e ${H%-*}-D ]; then rm $H; fi' \;
```

Comment: Never use `{}` in a `sh -c` expression: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/32931

Comment: One could assume there aren't likely to be rogue-named files in exim queues, but your warning is sound indeed.